# Nuxt Middleware throws Error: nuxt instance unavailable on refresh

Tags: vue.js, middleware, nuxtjs3

I know the solution is going to be obvious... but my brain is broken.
I have this Nuxt Middleware thats literally just supposed to check if a user is logged in and then navigate to the login if they arent. It works great! Unless you are logged in and you refresh the page. It throws a 500 error Nuxt Instance Unavailable.
Here is the code, I reverted it back to its simplest form:

```
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware(() => {
    const user = useSupabaseUser()
        if (!user) {
            navigateTo('/login')
        }
    })
```

Here is page code:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
    definePageMeta({
        middleware: ['auth'],
    })
</script>

<template>
    <div class="flex items-center justify-center w-full">
        <DashboardAccount />
    </div>
</template>
```

I have tried using to from, I have tried having it check its own route to make sure it doesn't loop, but none of my solutions have worked. Is it because it is a SPA? Why would the middleware run more than once? Wouldn't it complete its navigation and be done with it?

Comment: Can you provide a reproduction that we can check? Based on your codes it should be working As for your question on why the middleware run more than once, it is because it runs on the server side and on the client side.  See documentation on when middleware runs
https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/middleware#when-middleware-runs